# Can I run 'Unit Test App' on Windows Phone 8.1 device via Visual Studio 2015

Tags: unit-testing, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015

this is my development environment,

```
Windows 10
Visual studio 2015 professional
```

this is my target,

```
run unit test on the windows phone 8.1 device
```

this is my question,

I create empty **Unit Test App (Windows Phone) Visual C++** project,

1. I run the default empty test under Debug x86, it works on emulator.
2. I changed x86 to ARM and connect with Windows Phone 8.1 device, it doesn't work, and display the message:

   > PhoneUnitTestApp1.dll cannot be run. Please create a Windows Store or Windows Phone Unit Test project.

I don't understand the message. The project I created is **Windows Phone Unit Test project** already. How do I run the Unit test on the device?

Answer (score 0):

Quote from the article:

> When you want to unit test your app, both the tested and the test
> project apparently must have platform “x86”. The resulting XAP will be
> unit testable, and run on the emulator – but not on your phone.
>
> When you want to deploy or submit an app, set the configuration to “Any
> CPU”. The resulting XAP will run on your emulator and your phone, and can > be submitted.

Check this - Looks like this is what you are exactly facing.
http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.in/2013/06/x86arm-configuration-gotcha-in-windows.html

Comment: I am confused with the situation as well as I try to get unit testing for WP81 app done on the device as my dev pc does not have hyper-v.. And MS pages claim unit testing on device should be supported https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn168930(v=vs.105).aspx